# How to get keyboard height before open with React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard

I need to know how I can get the keyboard height before it opens. I also know that I can get the keyboard height listening the keyboard events but I need get it before.

Is open the keyboard by code at the first time, get the keyboard height and then close it the only way we can get it?

Thank's for all!

Comment: can you explain why the keyboard height is necessary? maybe I can help you in some easier way.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?